# Laravel-Pdf pass language settings to the view niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I can't call @lang("offer.date") in view-template.I ve no access to the Language settings.

Package: niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

Here is my code:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/invoice', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

Comment: Which version of laravel u are using?

Comment: Laravel 5.7 
Package: https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf